# Can't get these div's to center

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get these div's to center (all 3 next to each other to be in the center of the page), however I cannot get them to center.

Here is how they look, as an example: http://callum.website/

Code:

HTML

```
<div class="containercontainer">
<div class="containerleft">

    <figure class="image-container">

        <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/430915/screenshots/2031943/untitled-7_1x.png" alt="eSportsy - eSports PSD Template" width="400" height="300">

        <figcaption class="clearfix">

            <h4>eSportsy - FREE PSD Template</h4>
            <p>in <font color="0ead99"><B>FREEBIES</B></font></p>
            <a href="" class="dlbutton" target="_blank">Download</a>

        </figcaption>

    </figure>

</div>

    <div class="container">

    <figure class="image-container">

        <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/430915/screenshots/2031943/untitled-7_1x.png" alt="eSportsy - eSports PSD Template" width="400" height="300">

        <figcaption class="clearfix">

            <h4>eSportsy - FREE PSD Template</h4>
            <p>in <font color="0ead99"><B>FREEBIES</B></font></p>
            <a href="" class="dlbutton" target="_blank">Download</a>

        </figcaption>

    </figure>

</div>

        <div class="containerright">

    <figure class="image-container">

        <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/430915/screenshots/2031943/untitled-7_1x.png" alt="eSportsy - eSports PSD Template" width="400" height="300">

        <figcaption class="clearfix">

            <h4>eSportsy - FREE PSD Template</h4>
            <p>in <font color="0ead99"><B>FREEBIES</B></font></p>
            <a href="" class="dlbutton" target="_blank">Download</a>

        </figcaption>

    </figure>

</div>
```

```
body{
background: #F3F3F3;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
color: #2A2A2A;
 }

h4 {
color: #fff;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

p {
margin: 0;
}

.containercontainer{
width: 66%;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width:100%;
text-align: center;
}

.containerleft {
height: 312px;
width: 412px;
font: 87.5%/1.5em sans-serif !important;
margin-top:20px;
display: inline-block;
text-align:left !important;
float:left;
}

.container {
height: 312px;
width: 412px;
font: 87.5%/1.5em sans-serif !important;
margin-top:20px;
display: inline-block;
text-align:left !important;
}

.containerright {
height: 312px;
width: 412px;
font: 87.5%/1.5em sans-serif !important;
margin-top:20px;
display: inline-block;
text-align:left !important;
float: right
}

.container a{
text-decoration:none;
}

.container img{
bottom: 0;
display: block;
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
}

.button {
background: #0084b4;
border-radius: 3px;
color: #fff;
display: inline-block;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 4px 8px;
position: absolute;
right: 20px;
top: 30px;
}

.button:hover {
background: #2D76B9;
color: #fff;
}

.dlbutton {
background: #0ead99;
border-radius: 3px;
color: #fff;
display: inline-block;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 4px 8px;
position: absolute;
right: 20px;
top: 30px;
}

.dlbutton:hover {
background: #0eb49f;
color: #fff;
}

.image-container {
border: 6px solid #fff;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 400px;
}

.image-container img {
-webkit-transition: all .4s;
-moz-transition: all .4s;
-ms-transition: all .4s;
-o-transition: all .4s;
transition: all .4s;
}

.image-container:hover img {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-45px);
-moz-transform: translateY(-45px);
-ms-transform: translateY(-45px);
-o-transform: translateY(-45px);
transform: translateY(-45px);
}

.image-container:hover figcaption {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: translateY(0);
-moz-transform: translateY(0);
-ms-transform: translateY(0);
-o-transform: translateY(0);
transform: translateY(0);
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .4s, opacity .1s;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform .4s, opacity .1s;
-ms-transition: -ms-transform .4s, opacity .1s;
-o-transition: -o-transform .4s, opacity .1s;
transition: transform .4s, opacity .1s;
}

.image-container figcaption {
background: #283449;
bottom: 0;
color: #fff;
height: 50px;
left: 0;
opacity: 0;
padding: 20px;
position: absolute;
-webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
-moz-transform: translateY(100%);
-ms-transform: translateY(100%);
-o-transform: translateY(100%);
transform: translateY(100%);
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .4s, opacity .1s .3s;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform .4s, opacity .1s .3s;
-ms-transition: -ms-transform .4s, opacity .1s .3s;
-o-transition: -o-transform .4s, opacity .1s .3s;
transition: transform .4s, opacity .1s .3s;
width: 360px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove the margin-left from .image-container.

```
.image-container { margin-left:0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the size of containerright (from CSS) from 66% to 92%. This will align all the divs in center as well as wouldn't disturb page responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
float: left;
float: right;
```

and they become centered.

Answer (score 0):

```
.containerright {
 height: 312px;
 width: 412px;
 font: 87.5%/1.5em sans-serif !important;
 margin-top:20px;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align:left !important;
 ...
 margin:0 auto; // add this
  }
```

Do the same for other container too Which is in centre